# Pass vector of pointers as an argument

Tags: c++, vector

```
void spawn_enemies(vector<Enemy>& enemies) {
```

I had that function, and it worked just fine to pass a vector of Enemy's as an argument.

However, I know have a vector of `<Enemy*>`'s, and it doesn't work so well, and I also tried to use:

```
void spawn_enemies(vector<Enemy*>& enemies) {
```

But it didn't work either, I get the following error on compilation:

```
src/Paxlure.cpp:32:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Enemy*>::push_back(Enemy&)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_vector.h:826:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Enemy*, _Alloc = std::allocator<Enemy*>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Enemy*]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/stl_vector.h:826:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Enemy’ to ‘Enemy* const&’
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `vector` of pointers, you need to `push_back` pointers, not objects.

```
vector<Enemy> enemies;
Enemy e;
enemies.push_back(e);
```

versus

```
vector<Enemy*> enemies;
Enemy* pe = new Enemy;
enemies.push_back(pe);
```

In the latter case, with dynamically allocated memory, you'll need to free it yourself: `delete pe;`. But you have to make sure you correctly manage the memory - don't delete it before you're sure the `vector` will no longer try to work with it. Or simply use smart pointers instead of raw ones.

Comment: …and make sure you know who owns the memory, so someone can `delete` appropriately. Better perhaps to use `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` or `boost::ptr_vector`.

Comment: Thank you, I was not pushing back Enemy* enemy = new Enemy(), it fixed it.

Comment: Another caveat with dynamic memory: be careful that it won't leak if something (such as `push_back()`) throws an exception. Smart pointers are about the only sensible solution to that.